# How do I purge/delete messages of a specific user in a channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I want to create a command which can delete messages of a particular user in that channel where the command has been written.

Command I want:

```
!clear <user> <no of messages>
```

Eg: !clear @tom 10

My code:

```
@client.command()
async def clear(ctx,  member: discord.Member, user, amt=5+1):
    await ctx.member.purge(limit=amt)
    await ctx.send(f"cleared **{amt-1}** messages", delete_after=2)
```

I am probably not even close to answering my question but I tried.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think that should do the job:

```
@client.command()
async def clear(ctx,  member: discord.Member, number : int):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    async for msg in ctx.channel.history(limit=number).filter(lambda m: m.author == member).map(lambda m: m):
        try:
            await msg.delete()
        except:
            pass
```

What i did is that i checked if the message author is equal to the user that we mention and if it's equal to it then delete his messages for a limit of the number we want.